# About redis max memory policy

Tags: java, redis

Now there is a redis, max memory policy is configured as "volatile-lru" by default. As we all know, when redis runs out of memory, redis will select some keys with expiration time and delete them according to “LRU” rules. Now suppose that all the keys in this redis have not set an expiration time. When redis runs out of memory, write a new key, will redis report an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a "OOM command not allowed" error on any write command. Read commands will continue to be served.

See [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bredis%5D%20oom).